# Error While creating socket?

Tags: android, sockets, runtime-error

I am trying to create a socket connection on android device .
But as soon as i write `Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.126",3000)` and run it gives me error as

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.senddata1/com.example.senddata1.SendData1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1818)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:230)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at com.example.senddata1.SendData1.onCreate(SendData1.java:66)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
10-01 16:18:55.509: E/AndroidRuntime(15664):    ... 11 more
```

Pls help me what problem i am facing.

Comment: You should read the documentation. I don't think you're using it correctly. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.Proxy)

Comment: Seems you are printing a null value using `Log.e()`. What exactly are you printing ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass direct ip address do like  this.You have to cast it i InetAddress type

```
private String ip="192.168.1.126";
InetAddress serveradd =  InetAddress.getByName(ip);
socket=new DatagramSocket(6000,serveradd);
```

Tt will create the socket for udp connection or You can use

```
Socket s=new Socket(serveradd,3000)
```